# Create a PowerShell Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[string] error

Tags: powershell, ienumerable

I can't create an IEnumerable on PowerShell.

My goal is another issue/type, but help me solve this "simple" one.

```
C:\Users\Me> $var = New-Object Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[string]
New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[string].
At line:1 char:8
+ $var = New-Object Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[string]
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Can anyone clarify where or what I'm doing wrong?

The final object have a property with *Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[...]* so that is why using this type.

Comment: Will this work for you. `$var = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[string]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable[TypeParameter]` is an *interface*, an abstract type that cannot be instantiated.

If you want an instance of a generic collection that implements `IEnumerable[string]`, create a `List[string]`:

```
$var = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
```

If you use PowerShell 5.0 and newer versions' `::new()` method, you can skip the `System` namespace prefix:

```
$var = [Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
# these will resolve to the same type
$var = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
```